# Car won't start/respond to remote or anything until headlights are turned on

Tags: electrical, starting, car

I have a 1998 Infiniti I30 in really good condition except for this issue I've been experiencing lately with increasing frequency. What happens is, and there's no surefire way to reproduce the issue, but it won't start (no click, nothing), the doors won't unlock via the remote - basically I get nothing. That is, until I start messing with the headlights. Once I turn them on, 9/10 times the car starts up immediately with no issues, and the remote and everything else continues to work.

I have tried to reproduce this issue on a few occasions to my mechanic but was unsuccessful (always works that way hehe.)

Any pointers on how to solve this/narrow down what the cause is would be absolutely appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: It sounds like either the vehicle security system or the body control module (BCM), or a combination of the two are at fault. You could try a manual reset of the system by unplugging the battery for about 30 minutes and see if it goes back to normal.

Comment: You could also try replacing the battery in the remote.  If it is low, you could find that it works intermittently, and it is sometimes easy to convince yourself that random intermittent failure is correlated with something that's actually unrelated.

Answer (score 2):

Remove and clean both of your battery cables and posts, put them back on nice and tight. If that doesn't fix the problem, start checking the main ground wires from the battery. You likely have a poor connection at one of those places.